# ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spyder, importerror, huggingface, large-language-model

Not sure whats causing this error but it occurs on Jupyter Notebook and Spyder when running the following code:
`'''!pip install peft
!pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes
!pip install accelerate
!pip install transformers
!pip install trl
!pip install torch
'''

import torch
from trl import SFTTrainer
from datasets import load_dataset
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model, prepare_model_for_int8_training
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, TrainingArguments
`

Tried updating all the import packages but error still not resolved. please help

Comment: This may not help at all because your packages may be installing to the appropriate place despite using outdated approaches in Jupyter; however, it will help your experience going forward & so I'll point out that current best practice when running an installation from inside a modern Jupyter notebook is to use the magic install command. For pip that would be `%pip install` (or for conda/Ancaonda-users, `%conda install`). See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about those commands. See the ...

Comment: <continued> [second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) to get a better sense about how the exclamation point use with pip and conda can lead to issues and confusion. The magic variation of the install commands actually insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active .ipynb. The exclamation point runs off in a temporary, separate shell instance, which may or may not be running where the kernel is.

Comment: As for the issue you posted... You should include the code formatted so it is readable with line breaks and also the exact full error trace back you get all as code **text**. There's a button in the editor that lets you specify code blocks so you can use that, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51145), although I think the button is just brackets now(?), see next link). For more on doing this & without using the editor button and instead using special text markup, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8508004). Read & follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .